# Inherting YAML templates on conditional basis

Tags: azure-devops, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have a Yaml template for DEV,ACC,PRD for Azure Data Factory. I also have one for a Web App.

I would want an extra option to deploy these together in one Yaml through inheritance(or re-use). So that I can deploy them individually or in group. Is it possible?

This is the sample of my yaml  template a

```yaml
trigger: none

stages:
- stage: DEV
  variables:
    environment: 't'
    system.debug: true
  jobs :
  - template: shared-build.yml
    parameters:
      location: 'westeurope'
- stage: ACC
  variables:
    environment: 'd'
    system.debug: true
  jobs :
  - template: shared-build.yml
    parameters:
      location: 'westeurope'
- stage: PRD
  variables:
    environment: 'd'
    system.debug: true
  jobs :
  - template: shared-build.yml
    parameters:
      location: 'westeurope'
```

This is the build part(not all parameters added)

```yaml
parameters:
- name: location
  type: string
  default: ''

jobs:
  - deployment: Build
    pool:
        name: Azure Pipelines
        vmImage: windows-2019
    environment: '${{ parameters.devopsEnv }}'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: self
          - task: AzureKeyVault@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '${{ parameters. subscription }}'
              keyVaultName: '${{ parameters.keyVaultName }}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameters and conditions in your yaml file:

```
parameters:
  - name: DEV
    type: boolean
    default: true
  - name: ACC
    type: boolean
    default: true
  - name: PRD
    type: boolean
    default: true

stages:
- stage: DEV
  condition: eq(${{ parameters.DEV }},'true')
  variables:
    environment: 't'
    system.debug: true
  jobs :
  - template: shared-build.yml
    parameters:
      location: 'westeurope'
- stage: ACC
  condition: eq(${{ parameters.ACC }},'true')
  variables:
    environment: 'd'
    system.debug: true
  jobs :
  - template: shared-build.yml
    parameters:
      location: 'westeurope'
- stage: PRD
  condition: eq(${{ parameters.PRD }},'true')
  variables:
    environment: 'd'
    system.debug: true
  jobs :
  - template: shared-build.yml
    parameters:
      location: 'westeurope'
```

You can choose the stages you want to run when running pipelines.
[image]